# Crear trigger para jalar el dato de otra base de datos linkeada y insertarlo en otra tabla

Tags: sql, sql-server, trigger

Este es mi trigger

```
ALTER trigger [dbo].[replicaCheckInOut]
on [dbo].[CheckInOut]
after insert
as

DECLARE @CO_EMPR VARCHAR(2)

SELECT CO_EMPR FROM [OTI-ECORDOVA\IOFISIS].[OFIASIS].TMTRAB_EMPR, [dbo].[CheckInOut]
WHERE [OTI-ECORDOVA\IOFISIS].[OFIASIS].TMTRAB_EMPR.CO_TRAB=UserDeviceId AND [OTI-ECORDOVA\IOFISIS].[OFIASIS].TMTRAB_EMPR.TI_SITU='ACT'

insert into [OTI-ECORDOVA\IOFISIS].[OFIASIS].[dbo].[TWREGI_RELO](TI_DOCU,NU_DOCU_IDEN,CO_EMPR,FE_REGI_RELO,NU_HRAS,CO_CENT_COST,CO_ORDE_SERV,CO_RELO,DE_OBSE,ST_TRAN,DE_OBSE_LOGS,CO_USUA_CREA,FE_USUA_CREA)
select TOP 1 'DNI',right ('000000' + UserDeviceId,8),@CO_EMPR,FechaCompleta,+ REPLACE (CONVERT(VARCHAR,HoraMinuto,108),':',''),'','',DispositivoId,'','','',status,InsertDate
from inserted
```

este es mi insert:

```
INSERT INTO CheckInOut (UserDeviceId,DispositivoId,CIOTDeviceId,FechaCompleta,Fecha,TiempoCompleto,HoraMinuto,TiempoMinutos,Hora,Minuto,Segundo,status,InsertDate) VALUES ('72124','6','1','2020-04-13 21:45:15','2020-04-13','21:45:15','21:45','350','19','25','00',1,GETDATE())
```

al ejecutar el *insert* quiero que me repliquen los datos en la tabla TWREGI_RELO de la BD OFIASIS ya linkeada con la otra BD y que me devuelva el CO_EMPR, pero al ejecutar el script insert me devuelve este error.

> Msg 208, Level 16, State 1, Procedure replicaCheckInOut, Line 31
>   Invalid object name 'OTI-ECORDOVA\IOFISIS.OFIASIS.TMTRAB_EMPR'.

Comment: Edita por favor y agrega la etiqueta del motor de bases de datos que usas

Comment: es sql server.. todo esto es para llegar a una tabla? [OTI-ECORDOVA\IOFISIS].[OFIASIS].TMTRAB_EMPR

Comment: USE [SIGA_HOB_ACT]
GO

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

es sql server si es para llegar a la tabla de otra instancia y base de datos pero ya estan linkeaDAS

Comment: que version de SQL utilizas?

Comment: sql server 2014, creo que es el la sintaxis de mi trigger

Answer (score 0):

Este error se puede generar por multiples razones, primero que nada seria bueno que hagas un test de conexion a tu linkedserver en SQL Server Management Studio, de esta manera:

**En Object Explorer, click-derecho en linked server, y luego click en Test Connection.**

o de esta manera:

```
USE master;  
  GO  
  EXEC sp_addlinkedserver   
     'OTI-ECORDOVA\IOFISIS',  
  N'SQL Server';  
    GO  
  sp_testlinkedserver OTI-ECORDOVA\IOFISIS;  
    GO
```

Por otro lado tienes un error en la forma como quieres extraer los datos de tu server remoto, una consulta hacia un servidor remoto utiulizando un linkedserver se estructuraria de la siguiente manera:

```
SELECT col1, col2 FROM [linkedservername].[databasename].[schemaname].[tablename]
```

En tu caso estas omitiendo el esquema y al final de la linea estas agregando una ubicacion local

```
SELECT CO_EMPR FROM [OTI-ECORDOVA\IOFISIS].[OFIASIS].TMTRAB_EMPR,[dbo].[CheckInOut]
```

Deberia ser:

```
SELECT t.CO_EMPR 
FROM [OTI-ECORDOVA\IOFISIS].[OFIASIS].[dbo].TMTRAB_EMPR t
WHERE t.CO_TRAB=UserDeviceId AND t.TI_SITU='ACT'
```

Tambien es muy importante que revises los requerimiento de seguridad para un linked server, eso lo puedes ver en este [LINK](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2008-r2/ms175537(v=sql.105)?redirectedfrom=MSDN)

Answer (score 0):

En tu trigger hay más cosas que quizá no sean del todo correctas.

Declaras una variable @CO_EMPR que nunca le estableces un valor, ya que la select que viene después no iguala el valor de la columna a la variable.

Además trabajas el trigger como si la inserción fuera única, y esto no es correcto. Una insert puede venir con varios values, por tanto el trigger, si haces una insert con más de una fila, fallaría.

```
Alter trigger [dbo].[replicaCheckInOut]
on [dbo].[CheckInOut]
after insert
as

-- UTILIZAMOS UNA VARIABLE DE TABLA PARA CONTENER TODAS LAS INSERCIONES
-- Como no se el UserDeviceId de que tipo es lo he declarado como INT

DECLARE @TABLE TABLE (USERDEVICEID INT, CO_EMPR VARCHAR(2));

INSERT INTO @TABLE (USERDEVICEID, CO_EMPR)
SELECT I.UserDeviceId, T.CO_EMPR
       FROM [OTI-ECORDOVA\IOFISIS].OFIASIS.TMTRAB_EMPR T 
            INNER JOIN INSERTED I ON T.CO_TRAB = I.UserDeviceId
       WHERE 
             [OTI-ECORDOVA\IOFISIS].OFIASIS.TMTRAB_EMPR.TI_SITU = 'ACT';

-- Ahora en la variable de tabla tenemos todos los user_id y su co_empr

insert into [OTI-ECORDOVA\IOFISIS].OFIASIS.dbo.TWREGI_RELO
    (TI_DOCU
   , NU_DOCU_IDEN
   , CO_EMPR
   , FE_REGI_RELO
   , NU_HRAS
   , CO_CENT_COST
   , CO_ORDE_SERV
   , CO_RELO
   , DE_OBSE
   , ST_TRAN
   , DE_OBSE_LOGS
   , CO_USUA_CREA
   , FE_USUA_CREA
    )
select       'DNI'
           , right('000000' + i.UserDeviceId, 8)
           , t.CO_EMPR
           , i.FechaCompleta
           , +REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR, i.HoraMinuto, 108), ':', '')
           , ''
           , ''
           , i.DispositivoId
           , ''
           , ''
           , ''
           , i.status
           , i.InsertDate
       from inserted i
       left join @TABLE t on i.userdeviceId = t.USERDEVICEID
```

Observa que la variable de tabla requiere una definición del tipo de dato que es userDeviceId.

[Trigger After Insert. ¿Cómo se hace?](https://javifer2.wordpress.com/2020/04/12/trigger-que-es-como-se-hace-y-como-funciona-after-for-insert/)